# How can I remove indexing from a lyx book?

Tags: indexing

I developed a book that includes extensive indexing. I added indexing before making some final edits and publishing the book. I would like an automated way to remove the indexing (so that I can - conveniently - re-use segments of the book). (I use a computer that runs Windows 10 and not LINUX.)

Comment: What was the process you used to add the indexing?

Comment: Maybe like it's shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339493 :)

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for asking. Basically, I used the "Insert index entry" button in one of the tool bars. (More precisely, I found [in my under-development book] an instance of a term I wanted to index and used the button to index that instance of the term. Then, I copied the term and indexing entry. Then, I searched for other instances of the term and pasted the term and indexing entry as a replacement for each [other] instance of the term. It worked. The resulting index was fine.)